# How can i copy the entire directory?

Tags: java, android, copy-paste

I want copy entire directory onClick in android.. How can i do it? 
I have:

```
String sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File srcFolder = new File(sdCard +"tryFirstFolder");
File destFolder = new File(sdCard +"/TryFolder");
```

And then i need the code to copy the entire content of `srcFolder` to `destFolder`

Comment: Well that's just going recursively through all the files and copying them across (or going deeper if they are folders, not files).

Answer (score 0):

you can copy directory from one location to other using this:

```
public static void copyDirectoryOneLocationToAnotherLocation(File sourceLocation, File targetLocation)
        throws IOException {

    if (sourceLocation.isDirectory()) {
        if (!targetLocation.exists()) {
            targetLocation.mkdir();
        }

        String[] children = sourceLocation.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceLocation.listFiles().length; i++) {

            copyDirectoryOneLocationToAnotherLocation(new File(sourceLocation, children[i]),
                    new File(targetLocation, children[i]));
        }
    } else {

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceLocation);

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetLocation);

        // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }

}
```

also this link will help you to copy or move files from one folder to other:
http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/04/copy-or-move-file-from-one-directory-to.html

Comment: But how can i decide which is the sourceLocation and targetLocation using this code?? and how can i call this method in onClick?